# Python 2 dicts merge

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I am creating a dict to hold name and phone number, storing to local by pickle. 
the issue now I am facing is: it seems like  the merge is not working fine.
, any idea? thanks.

```
import pickle
def add(name,contact):
    person= {};  
    person[name] = contact;
    print('new added: ',person);

    mycontactfile = 'contactlist.txt';
    f = open(mycontactfile,'rb');
    storedcontact = pickle.load(f);
    f.close();
    print('saved list:',storedcontact);

    storedcontact.update(person); # add a new contact to the list

    f = open(mycontactfile,'wb');
    pickle.dump(storedcontact,f);

    print('now full list is:' ,storedcontact);
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, you dont have to use `;` to indicate the end of line, like in C or C++

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge (union) two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-union-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: I found the reason, person and storedcontact has the same key, so output only shows one. thank you all though

Comment: Show exactly what the problem is.  We can't guess what "not working fine" means.  Note that instead of `update()`, you could more simply do `storedcontact[name] = contact`, and get rid of the `person` dict.

Comment: @thefourtheye Can you go to the chat? I want to ask something

Comment: instead of pickling every time you `add`, why don't you just use `shelve` and let it take care of serializing...

Comment: update is updating an existing dictionary ... I think you want a list of dictionaries ...

Comment: the output for above initially is
new added:  {'a': '1'}
saved list: {'a': '1'}
now full list is: {'a': '1'}, even though I add second record {'a':'1'}, the full list still shows {'a': '1'}, as I suppose to see 2 records. however I think I miss some logic, when the second record contains the same key in the dict, then it will be update(override the existing one) instead of inserting a fresh record.

Comment: being said, the code above is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple contacts to go with a name, you'll need a `dict` of `list`. You would add contacts like this

```
if name in storedcontact:
    storedcontact.append(contact)
else:
    storedcontact[name] = contact
```

Better yet, stop using pickles and switch to [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

Aside:
    you can also initialise `person` in one step like this (but you don't really need `person` anymore)

```
person = {name: contact}
```